# Add function to a jQuery element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a function to an object with jQuery.
Unfortunately this does not work as expected. [This jsfiddle shows a minimal example of my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/9edvd5mj/) 
I just started with jQuery and reading the docs, but I need a hint in which direction I should go to solve my problem.

Thank you.

```
<ul id="ul_list">
    <li id="li_a">a</li>
</ul>
$("#li_a").speak = function () {
    alert("Hello I'm a!");
};

var button = $('<button/>').html('speak');
button.click(function () {
    $('#li_a').speak();
});
button.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help.

I found a solution for my problem probably no the nicest but works for me.

```
<ul id="ul_list">
    <li id="li_a">a</li>
</ul>   
$('#li_a') [0].speak = function () {
  alert('Hello I\'m a!');
};
var button = $('<button/>').html('speak2');
button.click(function () {
  var el = $('#li_a') [0];
  if (typeof el.speak == 'function') el.speak(); 
});
button.appendTo('body');
```

With [0] I get the DOM element I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the member function incorrectly. To do this, you need to [extend jQuery's prototype object](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/). You need to attach to `$.fn.speak`:

```
$.fn.speak = function () {
    alert("Hello I'm a!");
};

var button = $('<button/>').html('speak');
button.click(function () {
    $('#li_a').speak();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/w22aj7rs/

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.speak = function () {
        alert("Hello I'm speaking!");
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));

var button = $('<button/>').html('speak');
button.click(function () {
    
    $('li').each(function () {
        $(this).speak();
    });
});
button.appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing isn't working because jQuery's `$` function returns an new array-like object containing elements each time you call it. Mutating one of those only changes its instance, and the next time you call `$` to fetch the elements, it's a brand new array.

What you can do instead is use jQuery's `data` function to store the function inside the object:

```
$("li_a").data("speak", function() {
    alert("Hello I'm a!");
});
```

and call it with

```
button.click(function () {
    $("li").each(function () {
        $(this).data("speak")();
    });
});
```

Notice how the function must be called in the loop - we first access the data under 'speak' then call it.

This method works well when you want different behaviors for each element. If they all are to behave similarly, then you might be better off extending `$.fn` as the other answers describe because doing this assigns behavior to all objects.

Comment: Thank you. You are right I need different behaviors for each element.  I put your suggestion in my example http://jsfiddle.net/Mechanius/0q3vL3dr/ but with this data function I can't get a reference of my orginal object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0q3vL3dr/1/ here's a fiddle of what I'm suggesting. I removed the `p` element you had, but you can implement its behavior in the same way as the `li`s

Comment: Thank you again. But what I need is way to reference in the speak function to original element. For example if the lis are draggable (I think this is possible with jquery ui) speak should be able to return the actual position.

Comment: An option would be to pass the object (or whatever relevant information) into its own speak function while calling it in the loop.